# How to fix Blender in sculpting mode sculpts in wrong side of ear?

Tags: sculpting

When I sculpt from the side I need, it pierces from the wrong side. Sorry, for my bad English, but here's a video:
[How to fix Blender in sculpting mode sculpts in wrong side of ear?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A--P4nj2opw)

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found more appropriate answer by check for Plane Trim and setting value to 0.25 :

Result:
[How to fix Blender in sculpting mode sculpts in wrong side of ear? Use PLANE TRIM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qejm7APoY5g)

[image: Plane trim method to fix it]